# How to print package names that are being install with a loop in Ansible.?

Tags: ansible

I would like to print the package names each time ansible do a loop

```
  - name: Install base packages
    package:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
    vars:
      packages:
        - git
        - vim
        - htop
    register: echo
    debug: "{{packages}}"
    when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'
```

Comment: This is not going through a loop and all packages are processed in a single run, like if you where issuing a command as `sudo apt-get install git vim htop`. The exact order used to process each package depends on the package manager. For `apt-get`, I believe it uses a mix of alphabetical/dependency order (but don't take my word for it). This is actually the correct way to use the `package`/`apt`/`yum`/`dnf`.... modules in ansible and you should not loop other those packages for efficiency reasons. You could add a `block/rescue` stanza and display `echo.stderr` in case of failure for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your task definition is not looping through the packages. The `name` parameter can take a list of packages (which is preferred), and that is what you are passing as `packages`. If you would like to loop and have each package installed iteratively, you should have a loop with `loop: {{ packages }}`.

Something like below:

```yaml
  - name: Install base packages
    package:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    loop: "{{ packages }}"
    vars:
      packages:
        - git
        - vim
        - htop
    when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'
```

Now, every time the task "loops", the name of the `item`, i.e. the package name (e.g. `item=git`) will be shown.

Comment: Although this is indeed a correct answer to the specific question, it should be pointed out that it is a bad practice and that the code in OP's answer is correct: all packages are installed in a single package manager run.

Comment: Agreed, this solely achieves the purpose of showing each package at the cost of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be written more efficiently. I've added the debug part so you can see the actual output which happened on the target system.

```yaml
    - name: Install base packages
      apt:
        pkg:
          - git
          - vim
          - htop
      register: install_pkgs
    when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ install_pkgs }}"
```

Comment: This is very far from efficient as pointed out by [`apt` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#notes) => `When used with a loop: each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the name option.` Actually, OP's original code is more efficient.

Comment: I see, I've edited my answer. This should then be the most efficient solution. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well then this does not answer the question anymore. My point is that I actually think there is no good possible answer to this question. OP wants to see almost interactively which package is currently installed. This is not possible using the module correctly (i.e. passing names as a list) as you have to wait for the end of the task to see the result. And using a loop shows the package name for each iteration but is a bad practice. OP should understand ansible is not interactive, period.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think OP should refine/improve his question. One could take his question multiple ways.